# How to speed up the page render and operations of a dynamic HTML element (use ngFor and ngSwitchCase)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if, angular-dynamic-components, angular-ngfor

#### Problem:

I have a two-layer `ngFor` Angular template. Inside the `ngFor`, I use lots of `ngSwitchCase` to choose what kind of HTML element which I want to show dynamically.

This page is successful showing what I want but the render speed and operations of this page are a little slow in Chrome, not fast but accepted (But in IE11, it's too slow to use....)

#### Here is the template:

```
<form #qaForm="ngForm">

        <div *ngFor="let qa of qaList;let qIndex= index">

            <div *ngIf="!qa.hide">

                <div class="card-header bg-info text-white h5">
                    <label>{{'Q' + (qIndex+1) + '.'}}{{qa.question.questionContent}}</label>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div [ngStyle]="caseQuestionsService.getStyle(ans)" *ngFor="let ans of qa.answers;let aIndex= index"
                    [ngSwitch]="ans.dataType">

                    <div *ngIf="!ans.hide">
                        <div *ngIf="isDependPage">
                            <h6><span class="badge badge-secondary">{{(qIndex+1) + '-' + (aIndex+1)}}</span></h6>
                        </div>

                        <div *ngSwitchCase="'displayfield'" class = "form-inline">
                            <label class="ma mr-1 ml-1">{{ans.answerContent}}</label>
                        </div>

                        <div *ngSwitchCase="'newline'">
                            <br>
                        </div>

                        <div *ngSwitchCase="'textfield'">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q-{{qIndex}}-answers-{{aIndex}}" [(ngModel)]="ans.typedAns"
                                (change)="hideQAByIdx(qIndex, aIndex, answers)" #answers="ngModel" required>

                        </div>

                        <div *ngSwitchCase="'numberfield'">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="q-{{qIndex}}-answers-{{aIndex}}"
                                [(ngModel)]="ans.typedAns" (change)="hideQAByIdx(qIndex, aIndex, answers)" #answers="ngModel"
                                required>

                        </div>

                        <div *ngSwitchCase="'textareafield'">

                            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="q-{{qIndex}}-answers-{{aIndex}}"
                                [(ngModel)]="ans.typedAns" (change)="hideQAByIdx(qIndex, aIndex, answers)" #answers="ngModel"
                                required></textarea>

                        </div>

                        <div *ngSwitchCase="'singlecombobox'">
                            <select type="text" class="form-control" name="q-{{qIndex}}-answers-{{aIndex}}" [(ngModel)]="ans.typedAns"
                                (change)="hideQAByIdx(qIndex, aIndex, answers)" #answers="ngModel" required>
                                <option [ngValue]="null">select</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let item of ans.answerContentAry" [ngValue]="item.value">{{
                                    item.text
                                    }}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div *ngSwitchCase="'singlecomboboxu'">
                            <!--editable single selects-->
                            <app-input-select class="form-control" [selectAry]="ans.answerContentStringAry" name="q-{{qIndex}}-answers-{{aIndex}}"
                                (click)="hideQAByIdx(qIndex, aIndex, ans.typedAns)" (change)="hideQAByIdx(qIndex, aIndex, ans.typedAns)" [(ngModel)]="ans.typedAns"
                                #answers="ngModel" required></app-input-select>
                        </div>

                        <div *ngSwitchCase="'multicombobox'">
                            <div class="row col">
                                <ng-multiselect-dropdown class="col-12" [placeholder]="'select'" [settings]="dropdownSettings"
                                    [data]="ans.answerContentAry" (onSelect)="hideQAByIdx(qIndex, aIndex, answers)"
                                    (onSelectAll)="hideQAByIdx(qIndex, aIndex, answers)" (onDeSelect)="hideQAByIdx(qIndex, aIndex, answers)"
                                    name="q-{{qIndex}}-answers-{{aIndex}}" [(ngModel)]="ans.typedAns" #answers="ngModel"
                                    required></ng-multiselect-dropdown>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div *ngSwitchCase="'datePicker'">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control col-9" ngbDatepicker #dpEnd="ngbDatepicker" name="q-{{qIndex}}-answers-{{aIndex}}"
                                    (ngModelChange)="hideQAByIdx(qIndex, aIndex, answers)" [(ngModel)]="ans.typedAns"
                                    #answers="ngModel" required>
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" tabindex="-1" (click)="dpEnd.toggle()">
                                        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div *ngSwitchCase="'dateTimePicker'">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control col-9" appDateTimePicker #dpEnd="appDateTimePicker"
                                    (ngModelChange)="hideQAByIdx(qIndex, aIndex, answers)" name="q-{{qIndex}}-answers-{{aIndex}}"
                                    [(ngModel)]="ans.typedAns" #answers="ngModel" required>
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" tabindex="-1" (click)="dpEnd.toggle()">
                                        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div *ngSwitchCase="'customization'">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q-{{qIndex}}-answers-{{aIndex}}" [(ngModel)]="ans.typedAns"
                                (change)="hideQAByIdx(qIndex, aIndex, answers)" #answers="ngModel" required>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**getStyle(ans)**

```
    public getStyle(ans) {
        let display = '';
        let width = '';
        if (
            ans.dataType !== 'newline' &&
            ans.dataType !== 'textareafield' &&
            ans.dataType !== 'multicombobox'
        ) {
            width = 'fit-content';
            display = 'inline-block';
        }

        return { display: display, width: width };
    }
```

#### I'm thinking ...

I'm thinking of two ways to improve the speed of this page, but I am not sure about them.

1. Changing to use `ComponentFactoryResolver` to generate component dynamically. (I'm not sure about that's would be fast or not)
2. Generating a composed static HTML in Typescript then load them into Angular template? (I'm not sure about the detailed implementation)

Would anyone give me some suggestions on these two ways or **a new suggestion**?

Thanks for your help, Thanks.

Comment: Can you try removing binding to the function here ->  `[ngStyle]="caseQuestionsService.getStyle(ans)"`, Also add what that function does.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! 
I removed it, but it seemed not to work very much.

I have putted the code above ( caseQuestionsService.getStyle(ans) )

Comment: The code looks good, In my experience huge parity in performance between ie11 and others comes from using polyfills for IE while other browsers have native implementation. But your case is probably due to may be a large question set, can you give an idea of how many iterations are involved in each ngFor? Or in other words how big is your data?

Comment: Almost 20*5 = 200 iterations or 20*15 = 300 iterations, maybe 20 questions and each question has 5~15 answers, so it has 200~300 iterations, it's a big size, I know > <